# Как сделать подстветку кнопки при наведении? Bootstrap

Tags: css

Помогите сделать такую кнопку:

[image: *введите сюда описание изображения*]

Именно эту подсветку. Слева обычная кнопка без наведения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний: смысл вопроса «описан» картинкой, а не словами.

Answer (score 3):

Не обязательно делать через Bootstrap. К примеру можно через CSS сделать.

Касаемо цвета - можно узнать цвет через утилиту "Колориметр Digital Color (Mac OS)" или же через какое-нибудь Windows приложение. Лучше всего посмотреть код элемента, там где Вы этот цвет взяли и все. Можно конечно и через JavaScript это сделать, но думаю лучше через CSS. Вот ссылка на цвета (к примеру из поиска): [Названия цветов в HTML, CSS и JavaScript](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/HTML_Colors/HTMLcolors_HSB.htm)

Если есть желание сделать через Bootstrap, то Вам нужно перейти на их официальный сайт и там найти то, что хотите. Вот ссылка на русскоязычный сайт: [Bootstrap](http://mybootstrap.ru)

```html
<style>
.buttonChangeColor {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}
a.buttonChangeColor:hover {
  color:  #FF4500;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px  #FF4500;
}
</style>

<a href="#" class="buttonChangeColor">Кнопка</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Чистый CSS3, Bootstrap не затрагивает, но и не мешает ничему.

[Пример](http://codepen.io/peecaboo/pen/bpodKa)

```css
.about {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  padding: 20px;
  font: 20px/40px Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.about:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid darkorange;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.about:hover {
  color: darkorange;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px darkorange;
}
.about:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="about" href="">О компании</a>
```

Comment: Хороший пример, мне понравился )

Comment: @DenisBubnov о, спасибо :)